# Duplicated data displayed in the html page

Tags: angular

I've begun working with angular and I have a problem when I display the data from a json file. The problem is, that I have duplicate displayed data and this is my html code:

```
<md-tab *ngFor="let day of days" label={{day}}>
  <div STYLE=" height: auto; width: auto; font-size: 12px; overflow: auto;" >
<table>

        <tr >
          <th><span>salle</span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td *ngFor="let slot of slotss">
            <md-card  style="height: 70px; width:90px;">
              <md-card-content>{{slot.roomName}}</md-card-content>
            </md-card>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let slot of slotss">
          <th><md-card>{{slot.fromTime}}-{{slot.toTime}}</md-card></th>
          <td><app-rows></app-rows></td>
        </tr>

</table>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't know how can i do it but i think that is readable

Comment: can you post your component's class code?

Comment: ok @danimal   :  this is the service class :